# Laravel 8 strange behaviour with routes

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

Recently I lunched a new laravel app to a shared hosting and I have an issue with routing:

Everything works fine on my local machine and I get the routes exactly as specified in the routes folder. On the hosting, however, everything goes after /public/ directory.

So for example:

```
{{ route('leads.index') }}
```

in a blade file, on local machine will lead to:
127.0.0.1:8000/leads and it works as expected.

on the server however it redirects to example.com/public/leads

and trying to access example.com/leads redirects to  example.com/public.

My routes/web.php file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LeadController;

Route::get('/', [LeadController::class, 'index']);
Route::resource('leads', LeadController::class);
```

Root index.php

```
header("refresh: 0; https://example.com/public/");
```

Root server.php

```
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

The env file on local

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://127.0.0.1:8000'),
```

The env file on server

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'example.com'),
```

The route:list on server:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI               | Name          | Action                                       | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                 |               | App\Http\Controllers\LeadController@index    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user          |               | Closure                                      | api        |
|        |           |                   |               |                                              | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads/create      | leads.create  | App\Http\Controllers\LeadController@create   | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | leads/{lead}      | leads.update  | App\Http\Controllers\LeadController@update   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads/{lead}      | leads.show    | App\Http\Controllers\LeadController@show     | web        |
|        | DELETE    | leads/{lead}      | leads.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\LeadController@destroy  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | leads/{lead}/edit | leads.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\LeadController@edit     | web        |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

.htaccess file in /public/ folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the `root` path for your server in its config file?

Comment: @sergiu .better you point your domain to project public folder instead of root folder

Comment: @Peppermintology I only have 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'example.com') in config/app.php. Can't see any root path setting there.

Also in env file:
APP_URL=http://example.com

Comment: I mean in your `nginx` config file for example, there will be a line like `root /var/www/example.com/public` or similar.

Comment: @JohnLobo do you mean it's better how it is?

Comment: @Peppermintology I am on a shared hosting. Not sure where I should get it. I am updating the question with the .htaccess file